# Blender 3d reference images

Tags: model, 3d, blender, modeling

I been trying to make a 3d anime style face with reference images( front, side, and back views ) but I used a plane for each view.
But it has all 4 sides of the face but there in 2d and don't connect.
How do I combine the faces into a 3d face?

[image: planes of face image]

Comment: Sorry, did not get the sentence: "But it has all 4 sides of the face but there in 2d and don't connect". What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MartinSand sorry about that. Trying to say that I copied the reference images I had but there 2d planes with the face of the specific image. I don't know how to combine the 4 planes. There all flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start by watching a [head modeling tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20model%20head%20from%20reference%20image) to get a better idea of how 3d modeling works.

As you position a vertex in front view,

[image: front view]

you also need to go into side view and position the same vertex from the side

[image: side view]

as you add more vertices you get a 3d shape, not flat planes.

[image: 3d view]

There are several ways to create models, one is creating a polygon at a time, some prefer [box modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifFD8iD976g) where you start with a box or sphere and shape the model as you subdivide it to get more detail, while others find [sculpting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmBr3aTqT3U) more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand how the cycles engine works then you will be able to put your 3d texture in onto a material and do it that way. Otherwise, if you have all 4 images as image files you would want to go to the "Background Image" property and add them all in and set them to be visible on the side that they are meant to be on. Ie. Front on the front and left on the left etc.

When you snap to that view to use your reference you will need to make sure you are in Orthographic view to be able to see them correctly (Num 5)

I hope this helps!